# Week ending date, top 20 items by quantity not working correctly

Tags: sql, sql-server

I stink at SQL Server Queries (esp those with dates) and I am looking for some help returning a recordset. 
Basically I'm tasked with returning the top 20 items by quantity by the most current week ending date.If there are only 3 items for the most current weekending date, I would need to return only the 3 records.

Fields:

```
WeekEndDate, Quantity, ItemNo
```

Here's what I have tried so far...

```
select top (20) t.Item, t.WeekEndDate, t.Quantity
from ItemTable t where t.Quantity > 0 
inner join (
    select  max(WeekEndDate) as MaxDate
    from ItemTable it      
) on t.WeekEndDate = it.MaxDate
order by t.Quantity desc
```

I think I'm missing another join or something to only return a max of 20 rather than always returning 20 records. 
Thanks in advance...

Comment: The `where` clause goes after the `from` clause.  Join specifications are part of the `from` clause.  In other words, move the `where` just before the `order by`.

Answer (score 1):

As I mention in my comment, the correct syntax would be:

```
select top (20) t.Item, t.WeekEndDate, t.Quantity
from ItemTable t inner join
     (select  max(WeekEndDate) as MaxDate
      from ItemTable it      
     )
     on t.WeekEndDate = it.MaxDate
where t.Quantity > 0 
order by t.Quantity desc;
```

If you know that there are at least 20 records on the most recent date, you could eliminate the `join`:

```
select top (20) t.Item, t.WeekEndDate, t.Quantity
from ItemTable t
where t.Quantity > 0 
order by t.WeekendDate, t.Quantity desc;
```

Of course, if there are fewer than 20 records, then you would get records from another day.

Comment: I'll give this a try. Is there any way to limit the recordset to just those records for the max(WeekEndDate). I can only return records for one weekending date. My bad on the where clause, it was a paste error.

Comment: @HackNSlashProgrammer . . . The first query should do that.